# How to re-use old weights in a slightly modified model?

Tags: conv-neural-network, pytorch

I have a CNN network built like this for a particular task.

```python
class Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.conv11 = nn.Conv2d(1, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv12 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv13 = nn.Conv2d(256, 2, kernel_size=3, padding=1)  



    def forward(self, x):
        in_size = x.size(0)

        x = F.relu(self.conv11(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv12(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv13(x))

        x = F.softmax(x, 2)

        return x
```

The model is stored using the torch built-in method like this.

```python
net = Net()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
state = {
    'state_dict': net.state_dict()
    'opt': optimizer.state_dict()
}
torch.save(state, 'model.pt')
```

I have increased a single layer in the network while the rest of the model was kept the same.

```python
class Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        self.conv11 = nn.Conv2d(1, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv12 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv13 = nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1) # (new added)
        self.conv14 = nn.Conv2d(256, 2, kernel_size=3, padding=1)  


    def forward(self, x):
        in_size = x.size(0)

        x = F.relu(self.conv11(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv12(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv13(x)) (new added)
        x = F.relu(self.conv14(x))

        x = F.softmax(x, 2)

        return x
```

Since the other conv layers are kept the same, is there any way I can re-use the saved model to load the weights to conv11, conv12 and conv14 ? Instead of starting to train from beginning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you trained the following model and now you make a minor modification to it (like adding a layer) and want to use your trained weights

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv11 = nn.Conv2d(1, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv12 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv13 = nn.Conv2d(256, 2, kernel_size=3, padding=1)  

    def forward(self, x):
        in_size = x.size(0)
        x = F.relu(self.conv11(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv12(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv13(x))
        x = F.softmax(x, 2)
            return x

net = Net()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
```

you save the model (and the optimizer state) with:

```
state = {'state_dict': net.state_dict(),
         'opt': optimizer.state_dict()
        }
torch.save(state, 'state.pt')
```

Your new model is (note that corresponding layers keep the same name, so you don't make conv13 -> conv14):

```
class NewNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NewNet, self).__init__()
        self.conv11 = nn.Conv2d(1, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv12 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.convnew = nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1) # (new added)
        self.conv13 = nn.Conv2d(256, 2, kernel_size=3, padding=1)  


    def forward(self, x):
        in_size = x.size(0)
        x = F.relu(self.conv11(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv12(x))
        x = F.relu(self.convnew(x)) # (new added)
        x = F.relu(self.conv13(x))
        x = F.softmax(x, 2)
        return x
```

Now you can load your `model.pt` file:

```
state = torch.load('state.pt')
```

`state` is a `dict`, state['opt'] contains all the parameters that you had for your optimizer, for example `state['opt']['param_groups'][0]['lr']` gives

```
0.001
```

Assuming corresponding layers kept the same name, you can recover your parameters and initialize the appropriate layers by:

```
net = NewNet()
for name, param in net.named_parameters():
    if name in state['state_dict'].keys():
        param = param.data
        param.copy_(state['state_dict'][name])
```

Comment: Plus it doesnt work. The line "param =   params['state_dict'][name] " doesnt seem to copy properly

Comment: in the loop, what is the "params" and where does it come from ? Can you please elaborate ?  is it like params = torch.load('model.pt) ??

Comment: sorry about that, fixed

Comment: Still doesnt work.. I have done this so far https://pastebin.com/wp6fG4P6

Comment: you're missing a `.keys()` call: `if name in state['state_dict'].keys():`